# Routing clients using Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'd like to implement NAT Punchthrough as part of a client application to allow clients to connect to each other when behind a router.  I'm hoping to use Azure Mobile Services to accomplish this, but in order to do so, the server needs to save the ip address and port of all incoming connections in a database (so that other clients can lookup the host, and connect back to the client that posted the data).

Is there anyway to acquire this connection (ip address & port) information in the server side scripts? If not, what alternative services exist that'll let me setup an API like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found got an answer on another thread over on the windows azure forums.

Headers are exposed through the mobile services custom api feature.  Additionally, azure uses a forwarding machine to route incoming requests to the appropriate vm.  This machine is a proxy which saves incoming connection information into the x-forwarded-for http header.  Thus, from a custom script, we can query for incoming connection information from the headers.  It should be noted that the x-forwarded-for header is supposed to include both the ip address and the port number.

Here's the custom api example given in the other thread.

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var ip = request.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
    response.send(statusCodes.OK, ip);
};
```

The other thread is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/a6aa306c-f117-4893-a50a-94418fafc1a9/client-ip-address-from-serverside-scripts-azure-mobile-services?forum=azuremobile&prof=required

Answer (score 0):

For the minute this isn't available. The Azure team are working on increasing the amount of information about the request to the script. As to timescales of when this will be available I'm unsure.